# How to keep ratio of a rectangular tool

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry

I'm trying to implement a selection tool like the ones in popular graphic editors like gimp or photoshop, that if you press Shift while selecting, it keeps a ratio. In the following code is the main portion of it, and for simplicity, I keep it as a square. 
What the code is calculate the mouse position, move the X,Y position of the Block class, and then adjust it width and height. If Shift is pressed, it makes a square. It works almost fine if I'm moving from a bottom right or left direction, but in others, it changes the position of the whole block. Any Solutions?

```
 private void ItemsControl_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs     e)
{
    if (((ItemsControl)sender).IsMouseCaptured)
    {
    Block = new Block();

    Point mpi = GuidesSnap(e.GetPosition((ItemsControl)sender));

    double dx = mpi.X - mp.X;
    double dy = mpi.Y - mp.Y;

    switch (draggingState)
    {
        case 0:
        if (Math.Sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) > 2)
        draggingState = 1;
        break;
        case 1:
        block.X = (int)Math.Round(mp.X);
        block.Y = (int)Math.Round(mp.Y);
        block.Width = 3;
        block.Height = 3;
        draggingState = 2;
        break;
        case 2:
        if (dx < 0)
        {
            block.X = (int)Math.Round(mp.X + dx);
        }
        if (dy < 0)
        {
            block.Y = (int)Math.Round(mp.Y + dy);
        }
        block.Width = (int)Math.Abs(Math.Round(dx));
        block.Height = Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Shift ? block.Width : (int)Math.Abs(Math.Round(dy));
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the ratio of something, then you just calculate one coordinate based on another. So as X changes, you set Y equal to (AspectRatio * X). Alternatively, you could use the pythagorean theorem to calculate the distance from the starting point and then use that to calculate X and Y - but the central point is the same: to maintain aspect ratio you need at least one variable to be based on the value of another.

Comment: I see, that's somehow what I did, kept the ratio of 1 in the example, so both sides are equal, but could be any other value that it wouldn't work as I move the selection through the area.

Comment: Well, actually the pythagorean hint is being of great help :)